# Blank screen when navigate through the nested material-top-tabs

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Have app like this Bottom tab navigator like this

- tab A (contain material top bar)

  - material top tab 1
  - material top tab 2
  - material top tab 3 (contain nested material top bar)

    - nested material top bar tab x
    - nested material top bar tab y
- tab B
- tab C

When press back button from the nested material top bar tab x getting blank screen. But material top bar is visible. when press tab item doesn't navigate. Nothing is happening(Only ios. android working fine)

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: This is the structure. We have a low code app building platform. According to the backend response we create our app.